# Can't get my Timer in Swift to fire in Playground

Tags: swift, swift2, grand-central-dispatch, swift-playground

I'm trying to make a nice timer using Swift and GCD. I find lots of blogs and even an entry in Matt Neuburg's book. I used the latter to put together my own variant in a playground:

```
import Foundation
struct Timer {
    private var queue = dispatch_queue_create("timer", nil)
    private var source: dispatch_source_t
    var tick:()->() = {} {
        didSet {
            self.update()
        }
    }
    var rate:Double = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            self.update()
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, self.queue)
        self.update()
    }

    func cancel() {
        dispatch_source_cancel(self.source)
    }

    func update() {
        dispatch_source_set_timer(self.source, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, UInt64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) / self.rate), 0)
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.source, self.tick)
    }

    func resume() {
        dispatch_resume(self.source)
    }
}

var timer = Timer()
timer.tick = {
    let now = NSDate()
    print("\(now)")
}
timer.cancel()
timer.resume()
```

I have no compilation errors. But the console at the bottom of the playground shows nothing. If I add

```
timer.tick()
```

It outputs the result of the current date, apparently executing tick function once. I followed Matt's example in his book pretty closely (making small changes for education purposes). So I'm left with not knowing if

A) It's just fine and will work fine when I move it to real code, it just doesn't show anywhere apparent in the Playground output
B) Somethings not missing and it's not really firing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a source has been cancelled by `dispatch_source_cancel`, it will never call its event handler again. You cannot reenable the source with `dispatch_resume` after cancelling it; you must create a new source.

To make your playground work, you must remove the call to `timer.cancel()`.

Furthermore, after the entire playground script has been executed, the playground process exits by default. If you want it to keep running, you need to set `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`.

So make the end of your script look like this:

```
var timer = Timer()
timer.tick = {
    let now = NSDate()
    print("\(now)")
}
timer.resume()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```