# What does this _dispatch_xref_dispose error mean?

Tags: swift, timer, grand-central-dispatch

This is a next chapter of [a question I asked a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379433/cant-get-my-timer-in-swift-to-fire-in-playground). I have this simplified Timer, it is inspired by the Timer object in Matt Neuburg's book.

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

class Timer {
    private var queue = dispatch_queue_create("timer", nil)
    private var source: dispatch_source_t!
    var tick:()->() = {}
    var interval:NSTimeInterval = 1

    func start() {
        self.stop()
        self.source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, self.queue)
        dispatch_source_set_timer(source, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, UInt64(self.interval) * 1000000000, 0)
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source, self.tick)
        dispatch_resume(self.source)
    }

    func stop() {
        if self.source != nil {
            dispatch_suspend(self.source)
        }
    }

}

var timer = Timer()
timer.interval = 5
timer.tick = { print("now \(NSDate())") }
timer.start()

timer.stop()
timer = Timer() // <<--BAD STUFF HAPPENS HERE

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

The problem is the point where I assign a new timer to the same variable. The basic use case is that I'm done with a timer, so I stop it, but then perhaps want to create a new one and launch it.

In a playground, that marked line gives the error:

```
Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION {code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

If I do something similar in my iOS app, I get an exception trace that looks like:

```
0: _dispatch_xref_dispose
5: MyViewController.scanTimer.setter
....
```

It doesn't seem to matter if it's a struct or a class. Same thing happens. I wondered if I needed a `deinit`, but I haven't found an implementation of that that makes it go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is actually causing your code to crash is when the system tries to dispose of the event source.  You can see this by calling `start()` twice in a row using your class.  During the second invocation you will see that the application crashes trying to create a new event source and assign it to the `source` field.

It is also true that if you don't call `dispatch_suspend` for the event source, that the crash never happens.  You can see this in your example if you comment out the call to `stop()` before replacing the timer.

I cannot explain that behavior.  I don't know why calling `dispatch_suspend` causes the crash when disposing of the event source.  It looks to me like a bug that you should report to Apple.

Having said that, it is not clear in your code why you would call `dispatch_suspend` and not `dispatch_source_cancel`.  When you call `stop()` on your timer you are done with the dispatch source.  If you were to call `start()` again, you would get a brand new event source anyway.  I recommend changing your `stop()` function to:

```
func stop() {
    if self.source != nil {
        dispatch_source_cancel(self.source)
        self.source = nil
    }
}
```

This has the added benefit of working around the crash.

If you will take the advice, I also recommend replacing your hard-coded constant with the dispatch library symbolic constant for the number of nanoseconds in a second:

```
dispatch_source_set_timer(source, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
    UInt64(self.interval) * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0)
```

I suggest this because the number of zeros is easy to get wrong and using the constant helps the reader understand what the code is actually doing.